# Delayed touch input with multitouch cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, multi-touch

I am working with a cocos2d multitouch-enabled scene and I am unable to detect touches properly. When one touch is held down and others are quickly tapped, the tapped touches stop giving outputs after the first one. Similarly, if another touch is put down and held and the initial held touch is released, the change is not noted. Once all held touches are released, the tapped touches all come through with about 0.001sec of separation. Below is a log of touch outputs, annotated with what I was doing (inputs I was giving) at the time.

```
2014-05-27 08:57:31.486 Rotation a1[233:60b] Touch detected. //Tapped left side
2014-05-27 08:57:32.066 Rotation a1[233:60b] Touch detected. //Tapped right side
2014-05-27 08:57:32.535 Rotation a1[233:60b] Touch detected. //Left
2014-05-27 08:57:33.002 Rotation a1[233:60b] Touch detected. //Right
2014-05-27 08:57:35.835 Rotation a1[233:60b] Touch detected. //Held touch on right
2014-05-27 08:57:38.587 Rotation a1[233:60b] Touch detected. //Tapped center while continuing to hold right touch.
2014-05-27 08:57:40.821 Rotation a1[233:60b] Gesture: Failed to receive system gesture state notification before next touch //Not sure what caused this to trigger. Was just tapping and holding at this point. This error does not happen consistently.
//Continued tapping around the screen. No output occurred.
2014-05-27 08:57:48.986 Rotation a1[233:60b] Touch detected. //Let go of held touch. Everything flooded through at once.
2014-05-27 08:57:48.987 Rotation a1[233:60b] Touch detected.
2014-05-27 08:57:48.989 Rotation a1[233:60b] Touch detected.
2014-05-27 08:57:48.991 Rotation a1[233:60b] Touch detected.
2014-05-27 08:57:48.992 Rotation a1[233:60b] Touch detected.
[...]
2014-05-27 08:57:49.005 Rotation a1[233:60b] Touch detected. //Final touch came through
```

I am rather mystified by this. I have also included my touch detection method below. It's just a log at this point, so I don't think it's involved in the problem.

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CCLOG(@"Touch detected.");
}
```

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: The failed gesture message is probably key. Are you using any gesture recognizers? Have you perhaps enabled one that may be built into cocos2d (don't think there's one though) or some other UIView which may be using a gesture recognizer? Do you have multitouch gestures enabled on your device (Settings app), like 4-finger swipe to switch between apps? Are you tapping near the top or bottom of the screen (ie builtin gesture recognizer for control center, notifications view).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I am using a UIRotationGestureRecognizer. Multitouch gestures are enabled on my device (an iPad), and I'm tapping in the center more or less. I've enabled multitouch in my scene with the line `[self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];` in its init method.

Comment: gesture recognizers interfere with touch handling, specifically they delay and can swallow touch events. Check the class reference documentation, there's a flag to turn off delay of touch events to make it more cooperative and/or limit the gesture to react only to touches within a specific area.

Comment: `[_rotationRecognizer delaysTouchesBegan]` returns NO, so I don't think it's the issue. Also, how do I set those flags? When trying to set delaysTouchesBegan it said the property was readonly.